# How to prevent from clicked links to change color?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to coding (just getting started) :). I want to prevent from my link to change its color when clicked.
Can someone help? Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/link-pseudo-classes-in-order/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CSS pseudo classes to style links.
Like this:

```
a:visited{
  color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use :visited . here is an example:

```
a:visited { 
    color: #333;
}
```

Just set it to the color you want it to be when it has been clicked. Here is some documentation: [W3](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_visited.asp)

Answer (score 1):

To prevent clicked links from changing color you could do

```
a:visited {
    color: inherit;
}
```